# Why this multi-threading is slower than single thread

Tags: python

This is my first time to use multi-threading..

I write a code to process every file in a directory like:

```
list_battle=[] 
start = time.time()
for filepath in pathlib.Path(dir_battle).glob('**/*'):  
    battle_json = gzip.GzipFile(filepath,'rb').read().decode("utf-8")  
    battle_id = eval(type_cmd)
    list_battle.append((battle_id, battle_json)) 

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

it shows the code runs **8.74** seconds.

Then, I tried to use multi-threading as follows:

```
# define function to process each file
def get_file_data(path, cmd, result_list):
    data_json = gzip.GzipFile(path,'rb').read().decode("utf-8")   
    data_id = eval(cmd) 
    result_list.append((battle_id, battle_json))

# start to run multi-threading
pool = Pool(5)
start = time.time()
for filepath in pathlib.Path(dir_battle).glob('**/*'):   
    pool.apply_async( get_file_data(filepath, type_cmd, list_battle) )

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

However, the result shows it takes **12.36** seconds!

In my view, in single threading, in each turn of loop, the loop waits for the single thread to finish codes and then starts the next turn; while in multi-processing, 1st turn, the loop calls `thread1` to run the codes, then 2nd turn calls `thread2` to run.... during this job dispatching for other 4 threads, `thread1` is running and when the 6th turn arrives, it should finishes its job and the loop could directly ask it to run the code of 6th trun...

So this should be quicker than single thread...Why the code with multi-processing runs even slower? How to address this issue? What is wrong with my thinking?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing does not reduce your processing time unless your process has a lot of dead time (waiting). The main purpose of multiprocessing is parallelism of different tasks at the burden of context switching. Whenever you switch from one task to another, interupting the previous one, your program needs to store all variables for the former task and get the ones from the new one. This takes time as well.
This means the shorter the time you spend per task, the less efficient (in regards of computing time) your multiprocessing is.

Comment: Hi @po.pe Thanks for your reply. I read some material it seems I already create a thread pool and `apply_async` is using treads to run tasks in parallel. Why this is still multiprocessing not multithreading? What is wrong...